# how to pass value from a boostrap modal child to parent?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I been trying to pass any value from my window modal child to the parent window, but it doesn't work.  The `modal` doesn't `hide` or send the value to the parent window when I click `Save`.

**application.php**

```
<body>
<h3 class="h3 black">Application</h3>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="admin-controller.php" name="f1">
<input type="text" name="p_name" id="n1" > 
<?php 
    include 'includes/calendar.php';
    $calendar = new Calendar();
    echo $calendar->show();
?>   
</form>
</body>   
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0  /jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function post_value(){
    window.opener.document.f1.p_name = document.myform.skill_id_t.value;
    $('#modal_1').modal('hide');
}
</script>
```

**calendar.php**

```
<?php
class Calendar {    
public function show() {
    //some code
    $html .=$this->_showDay($someValues);
    //some code      
}

private function _showDay($cellNumber){      
   // Build up the html.
    $html = '<td id="' . $this->currentDate . '" class="td-top-text ' . $classNameOne .  $classNameTwo . '">';
    //Radio button that open the Modal window
    $html .= '<input type="radio" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_1" name="schedule_id" value="'. $shedule_id.'">'; 
    //singleModal
    $html .=$this->_singleModal();
    $html .= '</td>';       
    return $html; 
 }

 //child window
 public function _singleModal(){
    //Single Modal
    $html = '<form name="myform" method="post" action="">';
    $html .= '<div class="modal fade" id="modal_1" role="dialog">';//Modal open
        $html .= '<div class="modal-dialog">';//Modal Dialog open
            $html .= '<div class="modal-content">';//Modal-Content Open
                $html .= '<div class="modal-header">';//Modal-Header open
                    $html .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';//bbutton
                    $html .= '<h4 class="modal-title bold cyan">Sign Up (Single)</h4>';//Title H4
                $html .= ' </div>';//Modal-header Close      
                $html .= '<div class="modal-body">';//Modal-body open

                //Type something to pass to parent window 
                $html .= '<input name="skill_id_t" type="text">';

                $html .= '</div>';//Modal-body close

                $html .= '<div class="modal-footer">';//Footer open
                    $html .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';//button
                    $html .= '<input onclick="post_value();" id="save" type="button" name="save-details" value="Save">';//input
                $html .= '</div>';//Footer Close
            $html .= '</div>';//Modal-content close
        $html .= '</div>';//Modal Dialog Close
    $html .= '</div>';//Modal close
    $html .= '</form>';
    return $html;  
   }
  }
```

I read other posts and according to them, the problem could be `javascript` because I cant use `data-target="#modal_1"` with `javascript` so I tried to delete the `target` and just add `onclick` call a function into my `<input name="schedule_id">` to do `$(#modal_1).modal('show');` but still the `$(#modal_1).modal('hide');` doesn't work.

I also had tag `php` because according to other posts, I need to include the `javascript` into my `php` (`calendar.php`) and not in my `application.php`

**Edit**
I also got some error every time I click on `Save`

> TypeError: opener is null

Tried to fix it by adding `window.opener...` but it didn't work either

**New Edit:**

I have change my `js` code to this:

```
$(function() {
$('#btnLaunch_1').click(function() {
  $('#modal_1').modal('show');
});

$('#btnSave_1').click(function() {
  opener.document.f1.p_name = document.myform.skill_id_t.value;
  $('#modal_1').modal('hide');
});

 $('#cancel_1').click(function() { 
     $('#modal_1').modal('hide');
 });
});
```

and I remove everything that have to be with `data-target` including the one that close the window `data-dismiss`.  And, I realized that the problem is this line `opener.document.f1.p_name = document.myform.skill_id_t.value;` for some reason this line fail by giving the above error. `...opener is null`

Pleaseeee helpp =/ II am trying hard here....

Comment: I think in post_value you might need to assign the value to *p_name.value* rather than *p_name*.

Comment: @AverageUnknown thank you for your comment.  I changed, but still saying that `opener is null`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using *window.opener.etc* rather than something like *$('[name="p_name"]')*? I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using.

Comment: any reason, I got that syntax by googling solutions....any syntax is fine.

Comment: I've googled your syntax, and it looks like *window.opener* turns up null unless you used *window.open* to create your current page. Is that what you meant to do? If not try the syntax I gave you.

Comment: Can you provide a solution with your syntax?  I am not familiar with `js` and so, i'm not sure how `$('[name="p_name"]')? ` will appear in my parent window from the child window

Comment: In your post_value function, try replacing *window.opener.document.f1.p_name* with *$('[name="p_name"]').value*.

Comment: I've [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102739/discussion-between-averageunknown-and-ariel-maduro) so we don't clutter the comments any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after googling more and more and follow some suggestions from the first comment, I believe that the best way to get the values from a bootstrap modal child window and add it to the parent window is by using `jQuery` in this way:

```
$(function() {

//open modal
$('#btnLaunch_1').click(function() {
    $('#modal_1').modal('show');//no need data-target just <input id="">
});

$('#btnSave_1').click(function() {

    //Get the value from the child into a variable
    value = $('[name="skill_id_1"]').val();

    //Set the value to the parent window
    $('[name="p_name"]').val(value);

    //make the modal dismiss (no need data-target)
    $('#modal_1').modal('hide');
});

   //if user click cancel instead of use data-dismiss, just hide it
$('#cancel_1').click(function() {
   $('#modal_1').modal('hide');
});

});
```

If you find a better solution that this one, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your opener form name is wrong;

Change

`window.opener.document.f1.p_name` to

`window.opener.document.myform.p_name`

as you refer

`<form name="myform" method="post" action="">`